# ubuntu 13.10 jgrasp unable to compile due to javac error

Tags: java, 13.10

I am fairly new to linux and ubuntu. I have download jgrasp and installed all the necessary jdk packages. However when i try to compile a jgrasp program i get an error saying that javac is not in the folder i am saving the file in.
any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add the full error message to your question. I have a hard time to find out what exactly goes wrong in your case. Thanks

Comment: Execution failed: Cannot run program "javac" (in directory "/home/jim/Documents/School/NewFolder"): error=2, No such file or directory sorry about that thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

It's not saying it's not in the same folder as the file, it's saying it can't find it on your path. Make sure you have the full JDK installed, not just the JRE, and make sure it is the JDK "bin" directory that is first on your system path.

Comment: i have the open jdk 7 installed through software center. how do i get to my systems path?

Comment: Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + t and call the command `javac`, what is the output?

Comment: Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the

Comment: thats some of it it wont let me put in more